# How to output the list of problems that vscode shows when opening a JS file, by using only the terminal:?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

What is the default jsconfig.json or tslint.json that vscode are using to show me errors and warnings?

---

I would like to get all the problem in my JavaScript project. I do not have `jsconfig.json` or `tsconfig.json` files. I'm just using some files the `//@ts-check`.

Everytime I'm open a file `js` file, I see list of warnings in the problems panel. I would like to get the problems in all the files in the projects. No just the opened files. [VS Studio doesn't support it](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13953), so I'm looking to do if from the CLI.

I want to get the list using a CLI. So it can be part of CI process. I have tryied to using `tslint` and `typescript` CLI with my custom `tsconfig.json` and `tslint.json` but I never got exactly the same issues and warning as the vscode show me. I believe vscode have a default tsconfig and tslint that they use for showing the information.

I didn't find this on the GitHub of the typescript language server and the repository of vscode.

**In other words**: I'm searching for a command that I can launch from the terminal that will give me list of all problems that vscode will show me if I will open the same file in vscode.

[image]
*How to get this output using a terminal without having tsconfig or jsconfig files.*

Comment: VSCode shows a errors from not one program, but more. You can `tsc . && tslint .`, depending on what is activated in your VSCode. But the main one is `tsc` for TypeScript.

Comment: The problem is that I never successed to get same list of error. My tsc, tslint doesn't have same configruations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TSLint features a [CLI interface](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/usage/cli/), which can be used without any VS.Code.

Parameter `-c` or `--config` can be used to pass a `tslint.json` configuration file, as well as parameter `-p` or `--project` can be used to pass a `tsconfig.json` configuration file.

Passing the default configuration should result in just the same errors as VS.Code shows (at least, unless providing a custom per-project configuration override). It only reads "should", because I've setup a new SSD yesterday; but the presented concept appears quite likely for a *headless* CI environment (where attempting to run `code` does exactly nothing, klum, shumdabar).

you'd need to merge [tslint.json](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/tslint.json) and [tslint-vscode.json](https://github.com/palantir/tslint/blob/master/tslint-vscode.json) for an identical linter configuration.

Comment: Is it will tell me the difference between errors, and warnings? I don't see in the `json` file where it configurated if it's a warning or error. How vs-code knows to sepreate warnings and errors?

Comment: @AminadavGlickshtein it does not really differ that. it's more alike tests, which either pass or fail. there's only [formatters](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/formatters/), which can transform the output. [tslint-plugin-prettier](https://github.com/prettier/tslint-plugin-prettier) is also referenced in the config file.

Answer (score 3):

To see the errors that `//@ts-check` would generate, you can use the TypeScript compiler (`tsc`) with the `--noEmit` and `--allowJs` flags:

```
npm install -g typescript
tsc --noEmit --allowJs fileToCheck.js
```

`noEmit` means that no code will be generated but errors will still be output.

To run this for every file in your project, the best approach is to create a very simple [`jsconfig.json`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/nodejs/working-with-javascript#_javascript-projects-jsconfigjson) at the root of your workspace that defines your project and basic settings. The docs have more details on creating these, but here's a starting `jsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es2016",
        "jsx": "preserve"
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "**/node_modules/*"
    ]
}
```

Then run:

```
tsc --noEmit -p jsconfig.json
```

Alternatively, if you do not wish to create a `jsconfig.json`, you can try running `tsc` with every js file in your workspace using `find`:

```
tsc --noEmit --allowJs `find . ! -path '*/node_modules/*' -name "*.js"`
```

---

The above handles errors from TypeScript itself. However VS Code may show errors from multiple sources—such as typescript and tslint and a code spell checker—in a single file. There is no general way to get this from the command line.

Tools such as TSLint and eslint provide their own CLIs that you can use. This is what most open source project use for validation as it means that developers can use whatever editor they like. For example, your continuous integration script would run `tsc --noEmit -p jsconfig.json && eslint ... && ...`

However if you really, really want to get the exact same errors that VS Code shows in the editor, I believe you could use an approach similar to [vscode-test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-test) to run a script that controls a VS Code instance. The VS Code API  you'd want to use to get the errors is `getDiagnostics(resource: Uri)`

Answer (score 2):

The screenshot you provided showing that you are using the built-in Typescript comes with vscode, outputs with the `ts(<code>)` abbr.

**I think**, (Not sure for 100%) that the config for that Built-In Typescript is composed out of many configuration options you will see when you open settings and search for: "`typescript`" or expand the "*Extensions > TypeScript*" at the left side tree menu. **I think**, again: not sure, that the configurations are gathered and compiled at run time, never outputs to a file that you can capture...

The usual workflow though, is to get the official `tslint` extension:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin
Which is **not** the same thing as the built in one, and to get a basic `tslint.js` file, matching your team taste, which you can re-use at each one of your projects, then the `tsc ...` command will become part of your CI process, consuming the project's `tslint.js` config file.

The new extension will also output the problems to the problems section (outputs `tslint(<code>)`)

I understand that it's not exactly what you meant for, but I think it's the correct answer.

Comment: It's a good starting point, and thanks for the `TSLint` recommendation. Now the question is how to find the *default gathered compiled* configuration that VSCode uses, and create one for the project.

Comment: At the end of every problem line, at the screenshot you provided, you can see in grey color: `ts(2304)` this is to tell you which extension (or built-in extension) found that problem

Comment: This is the TypeScript compiler error codes. See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/dfd28d275100db73433318236a2299b002cf0ce3/src/compiler/diagnosticMessages.json#L1061

Comment: Yup but before the parenthesis holds that compiler code, the letters `ts` will indicate output of the **built-in** Typescript extension, vs the letters `tslint` indicates the output of the **installed** Tslint extension

Comment: Hoo. Good to know. I'm not used to the problems panel. Usually there are no problems in my code :)

Answer (score 0):

Go to your ESLint configuration in VSCode and then enable `Provide Lint Task` that by default is disabled.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't see this kind of configuration. And I don't see how it will let me gert the output to the terminal outside of vscode.

Comment: Oh you want to get that info but out of vsCode? Not in the vscode terminal?

Comment: Yes. Part of a CI proccess.